# Issues upgrading from Xcode 4.1 (4B110) to 4.2.1

Tags: xcode

I currently have Xcode 4.1 (4B110) installed via the App Store and it's telling me that there is no update, but the version in the app store clearly states that the most recent version is 4.2.1. Has anyone else had this issue and can possibly help me out in getting the most recent version installed?

Comment: Maybe you have delete the installation package that you have download the first time from the MacAppStore?

Comment: ..you cold also try to move/delete the Xcode.app from the application folder and reopen the AppStore - more info here https://devforums.apple.com/message/494607

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the AppStore Xcode 4.2 is not an update to 4.1 it is a new app. So you need to download the new app - at least now it is free. The app is only the installer as before so you will need to run the app to install Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I've just removed the Install XCode app, which forced the App Store to re-download xcode - at least I thought it would.  It didn't, it just re-downloaded the Install XCode app.

I figured out the solution though, just run the Install XCode app :)

Of course it's not obvious at all as the App Store was showing it as being fully updated when clearly it wasn't!!!!!  And the App Store is suppose to handle updates!!!

Answer (score -1):

I had to remove the package named **Install XCode** then click `Install` again in the AppStore  page. Downloading it now!